# MailMerge and Convert Docx to PDF using Apache-POI - Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I have a docx file which has merge fields. It incorporates an xls file to generate multiple records. Each record in docx is linked to a record in xls file. When I convert this docx to pdf using apache poi, it converts the first record ONLY. How to convert all the records?
Here is what I did:

```
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfConverter;
import fr.opensagres.poi.xwpf.converter.pdf.PdfOptions;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;

public class Doc2PDF {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static final String SOURCE_DOCX = "N:\\HSV_Letter1.docx";
    public static final String TARGET_PDF = "N:\\HSV.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Doc2PDF cwoWord = new Doc2PDF();
        System.out.println("Start");
        cwoWord.ConvertToPDF(SOURCE_DOCX, TARGET_PDF);

    }

    public void ConvertToPDF(String docPath, String pdfPath) {
        try {
            InputStream doc = new FileInputStream(new File(docPath));
//            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new File(docPath).toURI().toURL().openStream());
            XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(doc);
            PdfOptions options = PdfOptions.create();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(pdfPath));
            PdfConverter.getInstance().convert(document, out, options);
            System.out.println("Done");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {

            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "It incorporates an xls file to generate multiple records.": And the mail merge is done in `Word`'s GUI then. The mail merge results are not directly stored in the `*.docx` file. But `apache poi` is **not** the same as `Word` and only is able getting the data which were stored in the `*.docx` file. So do completing the mail merge in `Word`, save the result into a `*.docx` file and then do converting that file.

Comment: I opened the docx file. Clicked on Mailing -> Select Recipients -> Selected the excel sheet. Did Preview results. I was able to convert this docx file into pdf using Microsoft default Microsoft Print to PDF tool. But I was not able to convert this docx into pdf completely using above code. As I said, the conversion did take place but only first record was generated in the pdf. Please elaborate where I am getting you wrong.

Comment: As said the whole mail merge is done in `Word`'s GUI. Only the last filled data in the fields together with the reference to the `Excel` data source is stored in the `*.docx` file. And `apache poi` is not able doing mail merge. So in `Word` In the **Finish** group, choose **Finish & Merge**, and choose **Edit Individual Documents**. After that you have a new `Word` document containing the whole mail merge results.Do saving this as `*.docx`. Now this file can be converted.

Comment: Thanks a lot boss. It worked for me!